# What moments of Blue Gender considered causing huge controversy?

Tags: blue-gender

[This TV Tropes site](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/YMMV/BlueGender) about Blue Gender says:

> Actually, the series itself seems to be a source of great trolling on most anime sites.

What's the reason of it? Is there any worthy example to prove, show or explain?

There's another mention in said link that it is because of the ending, which, I can perfectly understand, but is also implies that it's not the only point of controversy.